# Simple_form does not accept the instance variable from action create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a very simple **StackOverflow** type of website
written in Ruby on Rails. I created four actions in my questions controller and one of them is **'Create'**.

I proceeded in the view page **index.html.erb** and I create a simple_form where I get **input(question)** from a user.

I get an error **(NoMethodError in Questions#index..undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)**

The question belongs to the current_user and I think that might be the problem. I thought maybe I need to initialize one more variable in order to get my form to work.

Can please someone tell me what am I missing here?

Thank you in advance!

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def index
   @questions = Question.all
  end

  def show
   @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
   @question = Question.find(params[:user_id])
   @question = Question.new
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(accepted_params)
  if @question.save
    redirect_to questions_show_path, notice: 'Question submitted'
  else
     @question = Question.find(params[:id])
     render :new
  end
  end
```

```
<%= simple_form_for @questions, @user do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <% f.input :content %>
    <%= f.submit :submit, class: 'btn btn-secondary'%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think the problem is with the 2nd argument to `simple_form_for`. What you want there is something that can resolve to a URL. `@user` could work if it wasn't nil... because Rails can guild a url off of an ActiveRecord object. So in this case you might need to set @user to a User model... Or use e.g. `url: my_named_route_path` as the 2nd option. Also make sure to use a non-nil instance variable to wrap the form around. So I think `@questions` should probably be `@question` from your `new` action.

Comment: Well I thought about that and then I put ```@user = User.find(params[:current_user])``` because I use devise gem in order to use the current user that it's logged in. It's more confusing because of devise. I tried with the paths and also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following code:

```
def create
  @question = Question.new(accepted_params)
  if @question.save
    redirect_to question_path(@question), notice: 'Question submitted'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Let me explain:

- on a create action there is no `params[:id]` (because we are creating a new item)
- also: we established that saving failed so trying to retrieve it from the database would only make sense on an `edit` action
- third: simple-form will look at the error-messages and incorporate them into the form, so the user can then fix the errors.
- and lastly: I fixed your `redirect_to` to be more "rails"-like, but this depends on your route-definition. I am assuming you have something like `resources :questions` in your routes (but if you do not give a parameter that could also never work imho)

E.g. if you have a `validate_presence_of :name` in your model, this could cause a validation-error upon save, and then we could present the field in red in the form when rerendering.

[TYPO in form?]

Lastly, after your comment I noticed it said `simple_form_for @questions, @user` and that should be either be the singular `simple_form_for @question`. If you want to edit the question as a nested path for the user, I think the correct form is `simple_form_for [@user, @question]`.

Comment: Well, I made the fixes above but it still gives me the same error.  it's highlighting the first line of the form. Thank you for your time tho.

Comment: I noticed your `simple_form_for` is not standard. Are you following any kind of tutorial?